# How to not return empty elements in for xml query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to produce nested XML report which comes from a table with dynamic fields and I would like to return only fields with values and the ones without values not returned at all with a FOR XML PATH  query in MS SQL

```
SELECT
 T1.[Col] AS '@id'
   ,T1.[Col] AS 'Event'
   ,(SELECT 
    (SELECT 
      Col AS '@name',
      (SELECT COl FROM Table WHERE COl= Col) as '@description',
      [Col] AS '@assessment'            
      FOR XML PATH('ininrow'), TYPE)
,(SELECT 
      Col AS '@name',
      (SELECT COl FROM Table WHERE COl= Col) as '@description',
      [Col] AS '@assessment'            
      FOR XML PATH('ininrow'), TYPE)

    FOR XML PATH('InInRow'),TYPE) 


   FROM [dbo].[Table] T1

  WHERE Col=12 
FOR XML PATH('OutterRow'),TYPE
```

I am expecting to produce XML without the empty elements if ininrow elements are null like so

```
<OutterRow>
   <ID>56789</ID>
    <Event>Vetting</Event>
    <InInRow>
      <InRow>
     <ininrow name="Bird" description="1: Black colar" assessment="BC2" />
     <ininrow name="Dove" description="White" assessment="W1" />
  </InRow>
 </InInRow>
```

but rather I am producing something like this

```
<OutterRow>
  <ID>56789</ID>
  <Event>Vetting</Event>
  <InInRow>
    <InRow>
     <ininrow name="Bird" description="1: Black colar" assessment="BC2" />
    <ininrow />
     </InRow>
  </InInRow>
</OutterRow>
```

Table 1

```
Id              
1000                
1002            



Table 2             
colA    ColB    ColC    ColD    colID
Bird    Black Colar Null    Null    1000
Dove    White   Bird    Black Colar 1002
```

[image]

Comment: Can you supply some sample data please?

Comment: Don't put sample data in your comments, @Tim, put it in your question; I can't read that data.

Comment: @Larnu tried to attach pic hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This **appears** to be what you're after:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (ID int);
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (ID)
VALUES (1002),
       (1000);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (ColA varchar(20),
                         ColB varchar(20),
                         ColC varchar(20),
                         ColD varchar(20),
                         ColID int);
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (ColA,
                        ColB,
                        ColC,
                        ColD,
                        ColID)
VALUES ('Bird', 'Black Colar', NULL, NULL, 1000),
       ('Dove', 'White', 'Bird', 'Black Colar', 1002); 
GO

SELECT 56789 AS ID,
       'Vetting' AS [Event],
       (SELECT T2.ColA AS [@Name],
               T2.ColB AS [@Description]
               --No idea where W1/BC2 comes from, so omitted
        FROM dbo.Table2 T2 --As Table1 has 1 column, I don't see why it's needed here
        FOR XML PATH('ininrow'), ROOT('InRow'), TYPE) AS InInRow --You've already used InInRow, careful
FOR XML PATH('OutterRow')       

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
DROP TABLE dbo.Table2;
```